# What does require('..') represents in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Recently, I came across `var Form  = require('..');`. I don't understand what `require('..');` means. Any idea what these two dots represent?

Comment: is it an example? require isn't native to javascript.

Comment: I guess you are asking about Node. The approach Node takes to resolving a `require` call is detailed here: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together

Comment: could also be module bundler such as [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/) or [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#multiple-bundles)

Answer (score 0):

So, when you require a directory in commonJS `require` statements, it looks for an `index.js` file. I'm guessing it has the following structure:

```
| Form/
| -- index.js
| -- subdirectory/
| -- | -- your-file.js
```

When importing `index.js` from `your-file.js`, you could do:

```
require('../index.js')
```

But, as a short-hand, I *believe* you could just do:

```
require('..');
```

This isn't really a pattern I'd recommend; as evidenced by this question, it's a confusing way to do it.